# angular 2 ionic 2 chat app adding dynamic component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i am building a chat app and fairly new to ionic 2 and angular 2.

I have the chat.html which looks like:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="chat-container">
       <div class="chatbubble-reply">this is a message dude</div>
       <div class="chatbubble">this is a reply dude</div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
    <form [formGroup]="chatForm" (ngSubmit)="sendChatMessage()">
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="messageInput" placeholder="start typing..."></ion-input>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button item-right ion-button clear large type="submit"><ion-icon name="ios-send" ></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </form>
</ion-footer>
```

my chat.ts looks like:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {
    private chatForm : FormGroup;
    private chatMessage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this.chatForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        messageInput:['']
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage');
  }

  sendChatMessage(){
    this.chatMessage = this.chatForm.controls['messageInput'].value;
    this.createChatBubble(this.chatMessage);

  }

  createChatBubble(chatMessage: string){
    alert(this.chatMessage);
  }

}
```

so the createChatBubble need to dynamically add the divs. I am ok if the chat part has to done differently in anuglar 2/ionic 2 way. Please advise